# Error: Spring Boot to integrate with IBM Message Queue: 'MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE'

Tags: spring-boot, rest, ibm-mq

for Integration with IBM MQ, I am using Spring Boot to create a REST API with services that will attempt to put messages in a queue as well as to retrieve messages from a queue.

I am using the following versions:

- Spring Boot: 2.3.1
- IBM MQ: 9.1.4.0

My SpringBoot application has the dependencies:
    1. mq-jms-spring-boot-starter (dependency): 2.0.9
    2. spring-boot-starter-web

I have install IBM MQ using the recommended installation, and chose NOT to configure a domain user id for IBM MQ to run under.

As for the Spring Boot application, I have built it according to the following:

```
com.mi.bootibmmqdemo
   BootIbmMqDemoApplication.java   ----> Spring boot runnable class

com.mi.bootibmmqdemo.controllers.mq
   BootIbmMqDemoController.java    ----> Rest Controller

com.mi.bootibmmqdemo.model.mq
   MqRequestMessage.java    ----> POJO request object
   MqResponseMessage.java   ----> POJO response object
```

I constructed the REST controller like so:

```
package com.mi.bootibmmqdemo.controllers.mq;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.JmsException;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.mi.bootibmmqdemo.model.mq.MqRequestMessage;
import com.mi.bootibmmqdemo.model.mq.MqResponseMessage;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/boot-ibm-mq")
public class BootIbmMqDemoController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BootIbmMqDemoController.class);

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @PostMapping("/sendMq")
    public MqResponseMessage sendToQueue(@RequestBody MqRequestMessage mqRequestMessage) {

        try {
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(mqRequestMessage.getQueueName(), mqRequestMessage.getMessage());
            return new MqResponseMessage("OK");
        } catch (JmsException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return new MqResponseMessage("FAIL");
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/receiveMq")
    String recv(){
        try{
            return jmsTemplate.receive("DEV.QUEUE.1").toString();
        }catch(JmsException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "FAIL";
        }
    }
}
```

My application.properties file contains the following configuration:

```
ibm.mq.queueManager=QM1
ibm.mq.channel=DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN
ibm.mq.connName=localhost(1414)
ibm.mq.user=admin
ibm.mq.password=passw0rd
```

Testing with Postman using the below JSON request:

```
{
    "queueName":"DEV.QUEUE.1",
    "message":"Hello World!"
}
```

I am receiving the 'FAIL' outcome, and in the logs I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.jms.JmsSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:286)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661)
    at com.mi.bootibmmqdemo.controllers.mq.BootIbmMqDemoController.sendToQueue(BootIbmMqDemoController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:424)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7815)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:236)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6016)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6041)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:494)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
```

While searching online for the potential cause and starting from the error code, I have found the suggestion indicating that the channel authority rule for whole queue manager needs to be disabled, by using command prompt (windows) navigate to the MQ installation directory, in my case it is: D:\IBM\MQ\bin

and running the following:

```
D:\IBM\MQ\bin>runmqsc QM1
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2019.
Starting MQSC for queue manager QM1.


alter qmgr chlauth(disabled)
     1 : alter qmgr chlauth(disabled)
AMQ8005I: IBM MQ queue manager changed.
end
     2 : end
One MQSC command read.
No commands have a syntax error.
All valid MQSC commands were processed.

D:\IBM\MQ\bin>runmqsc QM1
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2019.
Starting MQSC for queue manager QM1.


ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
     1 : ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
AMQ8005I: IBM MQ queue manager changed.
end
     2 : end
One MQSC command read.
No commands have a syntax error.
All valid MQSC commands were processed.

D:\IBM\MQ\bin>
```

I restarted the queue manager and restarted the Spring Boot application and re-tested with postman, same error is repeated.

UPDATE: adding MQ logs:

```
6/17/2020 08:17:06 - Process(24384.13) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(E107) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.1.4.0) QMgr(QM1)
                      Time(2020-06-17T05:17:06.756Z)
                      CommentInsert1(admin)
                      CommentInsert2(BootIbmMqDemoApplication)
                      CommentInsert3(N/A)

AMQ5534E: User ID 'admin' authentication failed

EXPLANATION:
The user ID and password supplied by the 'BootIbmMqDemoApplication' program
could not be authenticated. 
Additional information: 'N/A'.
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct user ID and password are provided by the application.
Ensure that the authentication repository is correctly configured. Look at
previous error messages for any additional information. 
----- amqzfuca.c : 4716 -------------------------------------------------------
6/17/2020 08:17:06 - Process(24384.13) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(E107) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.1.4.0) QMgr(QM1)
                      Time(2020-06-17T05:17:06.756Z)
                      CommentInsert1(admin)
                      CommentInsert2(DEV.AUTHINFO)
                      CommentInsert3(CHCKCLNT(REQDADM))

AMQ5542I: The failed authentication check was caused by the queue manager
CONNAUTH CHCKCLNT(REQDADM) configuration.

EXPLANATION:
The user ID 'admin' and its password were checked because the queue manager
connection authority (CONNAUTH) configuration refers to an authentication
information (AUTHINFO) object named 'DEV.AUTHINFO' with CHCKCLNT(REQDADM). 

This message accompanies a previous error to clarify the reason for the user ID
and password check.
ACTION:
Refer to the previous error for more information. 

Ensure that a password is specified by the client application and that the
password is correct for the user ID. The authentication configuration of the
queue manager connection determines the user ID repository. For example, the
local operating system user database or an LDAP server. 

If the CHCKCLNT setting is OPTIONAL, the authentication check can be avoided by
not passing a user ID across the channel. For example, by omitting the MQCSP
structure from the client MQCONNX API call. 

To avoid the authentication check, you can amend the authentication
configuration of the queue manager connection, but you should generally not
allow unauthenticated remote access. 
----- amqzfuca.c : 4739 -------------------------------------------------------
```

Kind Regards,

Comment: Check `D:\IBM\MQ\errors\AMQERR01.LOG`.

Comment: Why does the title include MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE, thar error is not shown in the question at all?

Comment: You are receiving a security error (2035 - MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED). Any more details of why are not given to the application for obvious reasons! You must read the AMQERR01.LOG as Josh told you to, to see what the issue is. If you don't understand what it is telling you, please add the error message you see in there to your question, so that we can help.

Comment: @MoragHughson yes I realize that the issue involves security configuration (or lack thereof). I have made the installation at: D:\IBM\MQ and there's no directory for logs. Possible installation error?

Comment: I could not find the mentioned log in the installation directory. In fact @JoshMc I could not find the '/error' directory', perhaps something wrong with the installation?.

Comment: found the '/errors' directory at: D:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\errors, I will edit to add the log info

Comment: Glad you found it - worth remembering to show all environment variables beginning with `MQ` - the `MQ_DATA_PATH` is the one you needed to find in this case. On windows, type `set MQ`, on Linux type `set | grep MQ`

Comment: it seems to be unable to acknowledge the security configuration i am sending through the Spring calling app. I did a work-around so as not to interrupt development but it's only temporary. I removed the queue manager connection authentication: from MQ explorer -> QM1 -> properties -> extended -> Connection Authentication and then I removed 'DEV.AUTHINFO' which I definitely think it's not optimal. Can you please shed some light or direct me to proper documentation to learn more? thx in advance.

Comment: It says `AMQ5534E: User ID 'admin' authentication failed`, is the user admin defined and do you have the proper password for it?

Comment: in the IBM MQ Explorer, Channel Authentication Records (IBM MQ > Queue Managers > QM1 >Channels > Channel Authentication Records) there is a defined channel profile "DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN" that has a client user Id of 'admin' specified. The entire queue manager QM1 is created by default after I had installed the IBM MQ. I cannot find where further information is defined, plus I believe the default specification of user 'admin' and password 'passw0rd' is predefined for QM1. Unless I am missing something or have it all misunderstood.

Comment: @JoshMc can you kindly share how to check these credentials? thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends on what type of authinfo object you have.   The check can be against the windows OS or against LDAP.  Checking either would be the same way you would check for any user respective to the type.